# How does Google Enterprise Search compare with Lucene/Solr/Nutch in search relevance for searching private documents?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, nutch

Does GES have an edge because it has access to vast amounts of data because of statistical analysis?

Comment: Because they're *free*? Your question seems to be asking us to critique a blog post.. this isn't the right place.

Answer (score 3):

If Google Enterprise Search is the Google Search Appliance: http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/solutions_productivity.html then I believe the answer is no in terms of tapping all the combined knowledge of the world that Google.com represents.

Google Search Appliance isn't Google.com, with all of the search expertise, custom algorithms, and magic tuning that those services have.  It simply crawls your data, and them make it's matches based on what content on your intranet it finds and indexes.

It is much simpler to setup, however we've talked to many folks who end up migrating away when:

1. the number of documents indexed grows to the point that GSA becomes very expensive
2. The desire for more control over the search results overpowers the admitted ease of setup that GSA has!   GSA is a total black box when it comes to relevancy.